# What is the rest of dividing $5^n$ by $7$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

It seems to repeat every 6 values of $n$:
\begin{align}
5^1 &\equiv 5 \pmod{7} \\
5^2 &\equiv 4 \pmod{7} \\
5^3 &\equiv 6 \pmod{7} \\
5^4 &\equiv 2 \pmod{7} \\
5^5 &\equiv 3 \pmod{7} \\
5^6 &\equiv 1 \pmod{7} \\
5^7 &\equiv 5 \pmod{7} \\
& \dots
\end{align}

So it seems to depend on the divibility of $n$ by 6, but I can't figure out if there is a better pattern such as an expression in terms of $n$, or how to prove it more formally.

Comment: Can you state how much familiarity you have with modular arithmetic? EG From what you've shown here, one can conclude that since $5^6 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$, hence $r^n$ repeats every 6 values ...

Comment: Mazel tov for spotting a pattern. Now, what is your question?

Comment: @CalvinLin I am familiar with the basics of how modular arithmetic works, but not so much with any theorems other than Fermat's. I didn't think that it was because of $5^6$, but it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Is the pattern just that? there is no single expression in terms of $n$? Also, how can I prove this more formally?

Comment: Multiplying by $5^6$ doesn't seem to change the result, did you notice?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem implies $5^6\equiv 1  \pmod{7}$ and so $ 5^{6k+c}\equiv 5^c  \pmod{7}$ for all integers $k$ and c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've discovered is called the **multiplicative order** of $5$ mod ($7$). It is the smallest integer $x$ such that $5^x\equiv 1 \mod(7)$. It is a fact that if $x$ exists for any particular congruence class mod(n) that $x$ must divide $\phi(n)$, which is Euler's totient function evaluated at n. If n is prime then this is simply equal to $n-1$ (as any prime is coprime to all numbers less than itself), and all congruence classes with a prime modulus are guaranteed to have a multiplicative order (more generally, if $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then $a^x \equiv 1 \mod(n)$ always has a solution). In your example $n=7$, which is prime, so the order of any element mod($7$) must divide $7-1=6$. Note that $\phi(n)$ may not always be equal to the multiplicative order, only that it must be divisible by it. For example, $2^3\equiv 1 \mod(7)$ and $3|\phi(7)$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't think it's fair to call my answer a dupe; after all, it's the first time I've made it